# Linux tcp server can't bind to a close_wait port

Tags: linux, networking, server, tcp

I tried to let tcp server bind to a close_wait port, but it caused a `Errno::EADDRINUSE` error.

I created a tcp server that listen on port 55555. Then client connected to that server. After some ops, run `ss -at | grep 55555`.

```
# ss -at | grep 55555
LISTEN     0      128                     *:55555                    *:*
FIN-WAIT-2 0      0               127.0.0.1:55555            127.0.0.1:16413
CLOSE-WAIT 0      0               127.0.0.1:16413            127.0.0.1:55555
```

I tried to bind port `16413`, it caused a `Errno::EADDRINUSE` error.
But if I connected to a ESTAB socket, the socket could bind to the port(such as 22385 below).

```
# ss -at | grep 55555
LISTEN     0      128                     *:55555                    *:*
ESTAB      0      0               127.0.0.1:22385            127.0.0.1:55555
ESTAB      0      0               127.0.0.1:55555            127.0.0.1:22385
```

Some scripts by ruby to reproduce the problem.

**tcp_server_close_wait.rb**

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 55555 # Server bind to port 2000
loop do
  client = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts "Hello !"
  client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
  client.shutdown(Socket::SHUT_WR)
end
```

**tcp_server.rb**

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 55555 # Server bind to port 2000
loop do
  client = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts "Hello !"
  client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
  client.close
end
```

**tcp_client.rb**

```
require 'socket'
include Socket::Constants
socket = Socket.new( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in( 55555, '127.0.0.1' )
socket.connect( sockaddr )
res = socket.read
puts res

sleep 10000
```

** tcp_bind.rb **

```
require 'socket'

# use Addrinfo
socket = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM, 0)
socket.bind(Addrinfo.tcp("0.0.0.0", ARGV[0].to_i))
```

Create `close_wait` bind.

1. run `ruby tcp_server_close_wait.rb`
2. run `ruby tcp_client.rb`
3. run `ss -at | grep 55555` to find client port
4. run `ruby tcp_bind.rb $client_port`

Create `ESTAB` bind.
1. run `ruby tcp_server.rb`

2. run `ruby tcp_client.rb`
3. run `ss -at | grep 55555` to find client port
4. run `ruby tcp_bind.rb $client_port`

Comment: Do some research about the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR`  has nothing to do with the problem. Every tcp server && client was created without `SO_REUSEADDR`。

Comment: Is `SO_REUSEADDR` is set on a socket in the `TIME_WAIT` state, then another socket should be able to bind to the same address as the closing socket is/was bound to.

Comment: My problem is that `close wait` can't be bind to, but `ESTAB` can be.

Comment: Remember that a local end-point of a TCP and UDP socket is identified by the protocol (TCP or UDP), the address, and the port number. If *any* of these are different from some other end-point, then they are different end-points. And end-point identified by TCP:*:55555 is different from an end-point identified by TCP:127.0.0.1:55555.

Comment: And please do what you should have done from the beginning: Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I also recommend you read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to lean some thing you should *not* do.

Comment: `*:55555` is just LINSTEN socket, It bind for `0.0.0.0:5555`, so other can use `127.0.0.1` or the wip to visit it.`*:55555` doesn't mean a estab socket pair.

Comment: I just show a tcp phenomenon， you can use every language or every command to reproduce it.

Comment: I update the problem with some ruby scripts to reproduce the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

I repeated the same test with Linux version 4.4.74-18.20 by using C programs.

I got different results than OP.

When SO_REUSEPORT was disabled, binding failed for both ports:

- port of client of established TCP connection (ESTAB)
- port of client of half open TCP connection (CLOSE-WAIT)

When SO_REUSEPORT was enabled (for all sockets), binding success for the both ports.

See [socket(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for getting more information about SO_REUSEPORT.